# I am trying to assign value for index[arr[i][j]]['x'], i am getting the Cannot set property 'x' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Here is my code for reference. I'm getting error for line 9 and 10. Is there a way to assign values for dictionary inside an initially empty dictionary :

```
function anticlockwiseRotate(arr){
            //store the index of elements in a dict
            let index={};
            for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
                for(let j=0;j<3;j++){
                    if(!index.hasOwnProperty(arr[i][j]['x']) && !index.hasOwnProperty(arr[i][j]['y'])){
                        //left shift by 2 and change rowInde)
                        //left shift by 2 and change rowIndex->columnIndex 
                        index[arr[i][j]]['x'] = (Math.abs(j-2));
                        index[arr[i][j]]['y']=i;
                    }
                }
            }
            let rotatedArr= [];
            for(let idx in index){
                rotatedArr[index[idx][x]][index[idx][y]]=idx;
            }
            return rotatedArr
        }
        console.log(anticlockwiseRotate([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))
```

Comment: There are too many things wrong with that function to even begin trying to fix it.  You should start by explaining what you want it to do.  What is your expected output for the line `console.log(anticlockwiseRotate([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]))`?

Answer (score 0):

set `index[arr[i][j]]` as object before assigning any properties to `index[arr[i][j]]`

```
index[arr[i][j]] = {};
//left shift by 2 and change rowInde)
//left shift by 2 and change rowIndex->columnIndex 
index[arr[i][j]]['x'] = (Math.abs(j-2));
index[arr[i][j]]['y']=i;
```